# Execute Unix cat command in Groovy?

Tags: unix, groovy

Hallo

I would like to execute something like cat /path/to/file1 /path/to/file2 > /path/to/file3 from a Groovy program.
I tried "cat /path/to/file1 /path/to/file2 > /path/to/file3".execute() but this didn't work.

After some searching I read about sh -c. So I tried
"sh -c cat /path/to/file1 /path/to/file2 > /path/to/file3".execute(), but that didn't work either.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you need to use the [`List.execute()`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html#execute%28%29) method to get this running in the Shell, ie:

```
[ 'sh', '-c', 'cat file1 file2 > file3' ].execute()
```

Or, you could do it the groovy way

```
new File( 'file3' ).with { f ->
  [ 'file1', 'file2' ].each { f << new File( it ).asWritable() }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! Can you possibly explain why we have to use the List.execute() method instead of the standard String.execute()?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need provide the full path to the executable? `"/bin/sh -c '/bin/cat file1 file2 >file3'".execute()`