# STDOUT does not work programmatically via Groovy API

Tags: linux, grails, cmd, stdout

Using `espeak` command to generate an audio

```
 espeak "Hello Mr. Toumi" --stdout > /tmp/audio123.wav
```

When i run this command using terminal , it works fine .

---

Prepare now in API for this command in Grails Service

```
#EspeakService.groovy
   File speak(String message){
       Process pr='espeak "'+message+'" --stdout > '+filePath(message);
        pr.waitFor()
        return new File(filePath(message));
   }
```

---

When i run : `espeakService.speak('Hello Mr. Toumi')` , there is no file generated and also no error message displayed . 
Any idea : Why does it not work programmatically ?

Comment: how would you know, that there is no error, unless you check for it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Execute Unix cat command in Groovy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008691/execute-unix-cat-command-in-groovy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java's external process execution mechanism is not a shell and doesn't support redirection using `>` like that. You should use a ProcessBuilder and do the redirection with that:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("espeak", message, "--stdout")
File out = new File(filePath(message))
pb.redirectOutput(out)
pb.redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT)
pb.start().waitFor()
return out
```

Comment: However , what about a further options like : `espeak -s 120 "Hello" --stdout /tmp/audio123.wav`

Answer (score 1):

redirections like `>` are done by shell.  either use `['sh', '-c', 'espeak ...'].execute()`.  or just pick up the `stdout` from the process, which would save you from dealing with a file.  e.g.

```
def p = "echo -n 666".execute()
p.waitFor()
assert p.in instanceof InputStream
assert p.in.text == "666"
```